# change active marker postion on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to change the active marker on click not on hover, but it's not working. When i change it to .hover it's still working but not my solution that i want.

How i can make it possible on .click?

Greets and thx for help!

```
// DOM Ready
$(function() {

/*
    EXAMPLE ONE
*/

/* Add Magic Line markup via JavaScript, because it ain't gonna work without */
$("#example-one").append("<li id='magic-line'></li>");

/* Cache it */
var $magicLine = $("#magic-line");

$magicLine
    .width($(".selected").width())
    .css("left", $(".selected a").position().left)
    .data("origLeft", $magicLine.position().left)
    .data("origWidth", $magicLine.width());

$("#example-one li").find("a").click(function() {
    $el = $(this);
    leftPos = $el.position().left;
    newWidth = $el.parent().width();

    $magicLine.stop().animate({
        left: leftPos,
        width: newWidth
    });
 }, function() {
    $magicLine.stop().animate({

    });    
 });

});
```

Comment: post the html too and if possible create a jsfiddle demo

Comment: it is possible in click event but one scenario can run. so use mousedown and mouseup event may it use

Answer (score 0):

Your code snippet doesn't change the class on the current clicked element.
You should try something like this:

**CSS**

```
#example-one li a:hover { 
 /* reset default style properties */
}
#example-one li a.hover { color: red }
```

**Javascript:**

```
$("#example-one li").find("a").click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault(); // stop default action on this element when someone perform a click
   var element = $(this); // assign the current clicked jquery object to element

   if (element.hasClass('hover')) {
      element.removeClass('hover');
   } else {
      element.addClass('hover');
   }
});
```